# Single column heat map in python

Tags: python, plot, heatmap

My goal is to have a single column heat map, but for some reason to code I normally use for heat maps doesn't work with if I'm not using a 2-D array.

```
vec1 = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(vec1, cmap='jet')
```

I know it's weird to show I single column vector as a heat map, but it's a nice visual for my purposes. I just want a column of colored squares that I can label along the y-axis to show a ranked list of things to people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the library Seaborn to do this. In Seaborn you can identify specific columns to plot. In this case that'd be your array. The following should accomplish what you're wanting

```
vec1 = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
seaborn.heatmap([vec1])
```

Then you'll just have to do your formatting on that heatmap as you would in pyplotlib.

http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: Works great! My only problem now is that I want to flip my X and Y axes so that my squares go up-down instead of left-right. There's no 'orientation' property in seaborn and transposing my vector doesn't work either. Any way to swap my x and y axes using seaborn?

Answer (score 5):

Starting from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834389/4458173), I've come up with an approach which uses both Seaborn and Matplotlib's [transform](https://matplotlib.org/api/transformations.html) to do what pavlov requested within its comment (that is, swapping axis in a heatmap even though Seaborn does not have an `orientation` parameter).

Let's start from the previous answer:

```
vec1 = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5])
sns = heatmap([vec1])
plt.show()
```

Using heatmap on a single vector yields to the following result:

[image]

Ok, let's swap the x-axis with the y-axis. To do that, we can use an `Affine2D` transform, applying a rotation of 90 degrees.

```
from matplotlib import transforms

tr = transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg(90)
```

Let's also reshape the initial array to make it resemble a column vector:

```
vec2 = vec1.reshape(vec1.shape[0], 1)
```

Now we can plot the heatmap and force Matplotlib to perform an affine transform:

```
sns.heatmap(vec2)
plt.show(tr)
```

The resulting plot is:

[image]

Now, if we want to force each row to be a square, we can simply use the `square=True` parameter:

```
sns.heatmap(vec2, square=True)
plt.show(tr)
```

This is the final result:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this works great for short vectors. But what if the vector data is very long? Can we make it wrap automatically to a new row or column?